# Required Rule on specific condition

Tags: yii

I need to apply rule on a form. I have a country and dependent drop down of state.

I need to apply required rule on state field.

But if i choose India from drop down then required rule should be remove from the form.

I have enabled clientsidevalidation true in cactiveform.

View form:

```
  <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                    'id' => 'cart',
                    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
                    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
                    'clientOptions'=>array('validateOnSubmit'=>true),
                    // we need the next one for transmission of files in the form.
                    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),

                ));     
        echo $form->dropDownList($modelUser, 'country', Countries::getcountrylistwithcode(),
        array('options' => array($currentCountry=>array('selected'=>true)),
        'empty'=>'Select Country',
        'class'=>'form-control input-lg',
        ));
        echo $form->error($modelUser,'country'); 

        echo $form->labelEx($modelUser,'state',array('class'=>"col-md-30")); 


        echo $form->dropDownList($modelUser, 'state', $stateList,array('class'=>"form-control input-lg",'prompt'=>'Select State'));

        echo $form->error($modelUser,'state'); 

    $this->endWidget(); 

    ?>
```

And model rules are like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('city,country,state,address_line_one,postcode', 'required'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a custom rule to your model.

Change your rules function to something like this

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('city,country,address_line_one,postcode', 'required'),
        array('state', 'validateState'),
    )
}
```

Next up would be to create the custom validation rule. This would look something like this

```
public function validateState ($attribute, $params)
{
    $aCountriesWithState = array('USA');
    if (in_array($this->$attribute, $aCountriesWithState) && empty($this->$attribute))
    {
       $this->addError($attribute, 'State is missing'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: custom rule does not work with client side validation. Any other way by this we can apply client side validation also?